# List the top 5 custom taxonomies from an author's custom post types in the WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

In my WordPress v5.9.1, I have custom post types (song, poet) and custom taxonomy (genre).

In the Authors page, I wanted to show the top 5 taxonomies from both pots types of a particular author with below code:

```
    <?php
                    $args = array(
                        'author' => 1,
                        'post_type' => array('song', 'poem'),
                        'number' => 5,
                        'orderby' => 'count', // categories with most posts first
                        'order' => 'DESC',
                        'taxonomy' => 'genre'
                    );
                    $categories = get_terms($args);
                    foreach ($categories as $cat) {
                        echo $cat->name . ' - ' . $cat->count;
                    }
                    wp_reset_postdata(); // reset query
                    ?>
```

The above code lists 5 random taxonomies than from the authors posts in the given post-types.

**Update 1**

Considering my objective cannot be achieved with above approach, I have tried below code using SQL Query and than `wp_get_object_terms`:

```
global $wpdb;

$SQLquery = "
SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID FROM $wpdb->posts 
WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type IN ('song', 'poem') 
AND $wpdb->posts.post_author = $curauth->ID 
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'";

$SQLqueryResult = $wpdb->get_results($SQLquery, ARRAY_A); // array of all posts IDs of an author for the post_type's

$SQL_post_ids = wp_list_pluck($SQLqueryResult, 'ID');

$SQL_get_terms = wp_get_object_terms($SQL_post_ids, 'genre');

echo '<ul>';
foreach ($SQL_get_terms as $term) {
    echo '<li>' . $term->name . ' - ' . $term->count . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

The above code results terms only from a particular author as expected, however what I am not able to achieve is:

1. Total posts count of particular author (`$curauth->ID`) for each `genre` term, expected in `$term->count` in the `echo`
2. Order the top 5 terms by most posts in each term.

How can I achieve the above two objectives?

**Update 2**

Below is the expected outcome from the working code:

(Name of the Genre [custom taxonomy] - Posts count [post_type = songs+poem] by an author in that genre)

1. Classic songs - 10
2. Romantic Poems - 8
3. Devotional songs - 6
4. Folk poems - 3
5. Patriot songs - 2

Comment: The documentation for `get_terms` refers to https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/ for the available arguments - and `author` is not one of them.

Comment: Okay, what are the alternatives to achieve this without querying all the posts to filter this data?

Comment: You could get all posts of these types for the current author, and then loop over those, get their categories, and do the counting yourself. Or make a native database query, that directly joins the relevant records from all the tables involved ...

Comment: That must be querying 100's of posts and performance impact.

Comment: WordPress's focus is on simplicity of its data model, not on maximum performance. But doing this via a native database query should not do to bad in this regard, I suppose, the relevant columns should be properly indexed already. The other alternative would be that you determine these counts whenever a post gets created or updated, and then store those as meta data of the user object. (But that approach would add even more complexity, you'd have to hook into all the right places, and such a system is hard to keep consistent as well.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have only two genres, then we can expect maximum two rows. Also, you can convert your query into a `group by`:

```
$SQLquery = "
SELECT count($wpdb->posts.ID) FROM $wpdb->posts 
WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type IN ('song', 'poem') 
AND $wpdb->posts.post_author = $curauth->ID 
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
group by $wpdb->posts.post_type
order by count(*) desc;";
```

Comment: The closing `"` has to moved to last row, I did that. Still it doesn't give me the top 5 custom taxonomies of both custom post_type's.

Comment: @theKing thanks for pointing that out. Can you tell me what your results are, why are they wrong and what should they be?

Comment: Your SQL query results are `null`.

Comment: I am trying to show the top 5 custom taxonomies of an author posted in two custom post_types, along with count of posts by author in each taxonomy. Posting the wanted example result in the main question.

Comment: @theKing are you sure the author you are testing with has song or poem posts? Also, how are the taxonomies stored in the database?

Comment: Yes, the author has such posts. With my current code (as in update-1), I am able to get the list of custom taxonomies from authors posts in custom post_types. What I am not able to get is the count of author's total posts from each custom taxonomy and order top-5 taxonomies.

Comment: @theKing I took your query (update1) and converted it into a query which returns the count, grouped by posts.post_type. Maybe there is a typo somewhere. Can you show us the result of `echo var_dump($SQLquery);` in your post? Also, a semicolon was missing from my code, editing my answer.

Comment: SELECT count(wp_posts.ID) FROM wp_posts 

WHERE wp_posts.post_type IN ('song', 'poem') 

AND wp_posts.post_author = 2 

AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'

group by wp_posts.post_type

order by count(*) desc;' (length=214)

Comment: @theKing if you execute this query as it is directly on MySQL, what do you get?

Comment: Strangely it returns ` #1146 - Table 'music.posts' doesn't exist` error, however it exists. I am getting the same error for my working code (in Update-1) as well.

Comment: @theKing this means that your query tries to refer a database which does not exist. What databases do you have in MySQL? Can you run `show databases()` in MySQL and tell me whether there is a `music` entry?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242893/discussion-between-theking-and-lajos-arpad).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to count the post for each term and then sort them by posts count:

```
$terms_with_posts_count_by_author = array();
foreach ($SQL_get_terms as $term) {
    $args = array(
         'nopaging' => true,
         'author' => $curauth->ID,
         'post_type' => array('song', 'poem'),
         'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'genre',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $term->slug
            ),
        ),
        'fields' => 'ids'
    );
    $posts_by_term = get_posts( $args );
    
    $terms_with_posts_count_by_author[] = array('term_name' => $term->name, 'term_posts_count' => count( $posts_by_term ));
}
```

Sort the `$terms_with_posts_count_by_author` by `term_posts_count` and then print it.

```
usort($terms_with_posts_count_by_author, function ($a, $b) { return ($a["term_posts_count"] < $b["term_posts_count"]) ? 1 : -1; });

echo '<ul>';
foreach( $terms_with_posts_count_by_author as $term_with_post_count ){
    echo '<li>' . $term_with_post_count["term_name"] . ' - ' . $term_with_post_count["term_posts_count"] . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Two quick queries? 1) How to show only top 5 terms only by posts count? 2) Can we do this without using `get_posts()`, considering 100's of posts...

Comment: For sure can be done in a SQL query but I'm not so good on MySQL.